# Replace all cells containing strings with a number

Tags: r, replace, char

I would like to replace all cells in a dataframe containing characters with a number (1).
Whats possible options is available in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this helps

```
d1[(`dim<-`(!grepl('^[0-9]+$', as.matrix(d1)), dim(d1)))] <- 1
```

Or

```
d1[] <- lapply(d1, function(x) {x[!grepl('^[0-9]+$', x)] <- 1
                               x})
```

Or

```
 d1[] <- lapply(d1, as.numeric)
 d1[is.na(d1)] <- 1
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
d1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(LETTERS[1:4], 1:10), 
          10*5, replace=TRUE), ncol=5), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```